# Algolia search (Scout) with multiples fields

Tags: laravel, algolia

Let' say I want to create a phone book for a big company with multiples offices.
My database is composed by 3 tables:
- User
- City (represent the office's location)
- Role (a User can have multiple roles)

I'd like to create a form with 3 different fields to perform the query, how can I do that ?

For now I've got only 1 field and this is my main model User

```

```
public function city()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(City::class);
}

public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
}

public function toSearchableArray()
{
    $office = $this->city;

    $array = [
        'name' => $this->name,
        'phone' => $this->phone,
        'postal_code' => $office->postal_code,
        'city' => $office->name,
    ];

    return $array;
}
```

```

How would you do a research with Algolia and add filters to the query (City and Roles) ?

How should I store Roles ? Plain text ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Scout only support numbers in the `where` clause: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scout#where-clauses

I would recommend to also store the ID for offices and do search like:

```
User::search('')->where('office_id', 2)->get();
```

For Roles, because you have multiple values, you should store them as in an array.
You cannot use `where` on arrays, so you will need to leverage the callback parameter to add a `filter` entry in the options array.

```
User::search('', function ($algolia, $query, $options) {
    $options = array_merge($options, [
        'filters' => 'roles:engineer'
    ]);

    return $algolia->search($query, $options);
})->get();
```

You can find Algolia's doc about filtering here: https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/searching/filtering/

Please let me know if that worked for you.